# Ativar e desativar função em jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Preciso desativar uma função em jquery, por exemplo, quando eu clicar em uma div, uma função que eu defini não vai mais ser executada, apenas quando eu clicar em outra div ela volta a funcionar. A função é carregada quando o site for carregado.
Preciso que quando eu clique em uma div essa função não funcione mais, apenas quando clicar em outra div ela volte.

```js
function executar_whell() {
    function debounce(fn, delay) {
        var timer = null;
        return function () {
            var context = this, args = arguments;
            clearTimeout(timer);
            timer = setTimeout(function () {
                fn.apply(context, args);
            }, delay);
        };
    }
    var scrollervateira = debounce(function (event) {
        if (event.originalEvent.wheelDelta >= 0) {
            $('.flexhome').flexslider('prev');
            console.log('passa_slide');
            return false;
        } else {
            $('.flexhome').flexslider('next');
            console.log('volta_slide');
            return false;
        }
    }, 250);
    $(window).bind('mousewheel', scrollervateira);
}
;
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

A função executar_whell não vai poder funcionar quando eu clicar em uma div ( div onclick=outrafuncao) e quando eu clicar em outra div ( div onclick-funcionar) ela voltara a funcionar.

Comment: Se colocares mais código é possivel ajudar mais, mas para essa funcionalidade que referes podes usar uma flag, ou retirar o event handler e colocar novamente com `.on()` e `.off()`, ou bund/unbind. Um à parte: essa defenião de função ` function debounce(fn, delay) {` não precisa estar dentro de `executar_whell`. Fica meio confuso estar aí.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

você pode usar o `addEventListener` para ativar o evento e o `removeEventListener` para remover o evento.

segue um exemplo com o evento `mousemove`.

```js
var x = document.getElementById("x");
var y = document.getElementById("y");
var track = document.getElementById("track");

var onMouseMove = function (event) {
  x.value = event.x;
  y.value = event.y;
}

track.addEventListener("click", function (event) {
  var ativo = track.dataset.ativo == "true";
  if (ativo) {
    track.dataset.ativo = false;
    track.value = "Ativar";
    window.removeEventListener("mousemove", onMouseMove);
  } else {
    track.dataset.ativo = true;
    track.value = "Desativar";
    window.addEventListener("mousemove", onMouseMove);
  }
});

window.addEventListener("mousemove", onMouseMove);
```

```html
<div>
  <label>
    X:
    <input id="x" type="text" />
  </label>
</div>
<div>
  <label>
    Y:
    <input id="y" type="text" />
  </label>
</div>
<div>
  Track Mouse: 
  <input id="track" type="button" value="Desativar" data-ativo="true" />
</div>
```

Comment: Isso mesmo, vou somente trocar, obrigado!

Answer (score 1):

Como complemento a resposta do TobyMosque, deixo uma opção com um efeito bem semelhante, porém feito em JQuery.

Para adicionar um evento em jquery você pode usar o `.bind()`, já para remover esse evento pode usar o `.unbind()`. Veja no JsFiddle abaixo:

### [JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3920und3/1/)

Um código bem simples como exemplo:

```
$('input:text').bind('keyup', function(){
  $('span').text(this.value);
})
$('input:button').click(funtion(){
  $('input:text').unbind('keyup');
})
```

Com o `unbind()` também é possível especificar a função em questão a se remover, juntamente com o evento. Por exemplo: `unbind('keyup', escrever)`, assim a função `escrever()` não será mais executada no evento `keyup`.

Não usei o Stack Snippet pois estou no mobile.